# Substring in Java with recurrent substring

Tags: java, parsing, substring

I have this string:

```
file:/C:/workWaveMaker/projects/AAA/webapproot/WEB-INF/classes/custom/
```

My goal is to parse only the string AAA in this case, but I will face othere similar strings where AAA is not the string, but something different.
Is there a way to solve this based for example on the recurrent string webapproot?

Comment: What about the rest of the string?

Comment: Nothing, I need only AAA

Comment: You might use a regular expression, if the pattern is indeed "/XXX/webapproot/" with "XXX" being the variable string.

Comment: Please show the complete set of expected inputs.

Comment: @user840718 I mean, what is the pattern for the rest of the string? Does that also change, or is it exactly the same pattern, with only AAA changed to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Pattern` class using regex to extract the `AAA`

```
String s = "file:/C:/workWaveMaker/projects/AAA/webapproot/WEB-INF/classes/custom/";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/projects/(.*?)/webapproot/");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) 
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); // => result "AAA"
```